# Determinate queued signals

Tags: c++, qt

Assume I have a `Qt::QueuedConnection` connection in which the signal is emitted in a different thread from the one the consumer slot is called. Now I want to close the application and in the handler destructor I would like to check either there are any remaining queued signal-slot calls (I am using this signal slot connection mechanism as a queue). Is it possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. Did you encounter any problems? If yes what were they?

Comment: I didn't encounter any problems. I would just like to know either within the Qt API it is possible to check how many siganl-slot calls are still enqueued.

Comment: I'm not aware of any API that lets you query the number of events pending but this feels like and xy problem.  Can you provide some code and/or a use case that clarifies why you want this?

Comment: Its more of a theoretical problem. I just wonder either a Qt program will wait before quiting for all queied signals to be handled or will they be lost.